# Strange build error in VS2010/C#. Building projects not completes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build-process

In our automatic build process we use visual studio command line (by some reasons we can't use msbuild):

`devenv.exe /build ....`

it was works correctly for years, but recently we moved to other build machine. Sometime (rare) build failed with stgange error. More precisely - here is no error for some projects. Projects started and nothing more:

```
....
62>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\FramModuleork\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "D:\Autobuild\10.0\dotNET_tc\My.Legacy\bin\x64\Release\My.Legacy.dll", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtMye failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
62> My.Srv.User -> D:\GFIN_Autobuild\gfin_10.0\dotNET_tc\My.Srv.User\bin\My.Srv.User.dll
63>------ Build started: Project: My.Srv.Admin, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
64>------ Build started: Project: My.ExportProcessor, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
65>------ Build started: Project: My.Srv.MSSQLConnector, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
66>------ Build started: Project: My.Server.Ita, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
67>------ Build started: Project: My.Server.Rca, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
68>------ Build started: Project: My.Server.Module, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
69>------ Build started: Project: My.Server.DB2, Configuration: Release x64 ------
70>------ Build started: Project: My.Server.Server, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
71>------ Build started: Project: My.Server.Module.Specific, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
72>------ Build started: Project: My.Patterns.Data, Configuration: Release x64 ------
73>------ Build started: Project: My.Server.DatabaseWeb, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
74>------ Build started: Project: My.Srv.Client, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
========== Build: 59 succeeded, 15 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

We change host for out virtual build machine, we reinstall OS on build machine but error still appeared sometime.

Any thoughts?

P.S. we start builds from Jenkins and TeamCity. In both error was reproduced.

Comment: I haven't seen this error before but my wild guess would be that the OS on your build server is 32 bit and you try to build a 64 bit application.

Comment: thanks for guess, but no - we use x64. Moreover - previous build server was 32bit and has no problems.

Comment: Did you clean your solution? The first line of your error throws me a off a bit. The computer is talking about something being AMD64 (64bit) while something else is set to enforce 32 bit. It is possible to run 32bit applications on windows but you'll have to emulate those as a x86 ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384249(v=vs.85).aspx ) so  you cant enforce true 32 bit. I'd clean my build if I where you and double check if you are perhaps using a DLL that enforces a certain processor architecture.

Comment: `while something else is set to enforce 32 bit`

no, we have Assembly1 compiled as MSIL (AnyCPU) and it uses other assembly which has both versions (x86 and x64). This is correct situation, because we need to use Assembly1 from x64 and x86 processes.